# CountRoots[] won't count my roots. Can I force it to?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, complex

I have a big messy function consisting of lots of combined Bessel and Hankel functions that I want to count the roots of. Mathematica doesn't want to try though because it can't prove the function is meromorphic. Is there a way I can get it to proceed anyway?

Here's the error:

> CountRoots::nmero: CountRoots was unable to show that [snip] is a univariate meromorphic function of x in [0, 28086791066474663936].

So can I get mathematica to trust me and proceed anyway without first having to show that the function is meromorphic?

Thanking you in advance,
Ben

Comment: Hard to do much of anything without the actual code.

Comment: You want to see the actual function? Unfortunately it is 384 characters too long to post in a comment here...

Comment: It's a general question though - I'm not interested in the properties of my function itself - I just want to know if I can get mathematica to ignore the fact it can't prove it meromorphic.

Comment: The mathematica code where I call CountRoots[] is literally just:

NR = CountRoots[FUNCTION[x], {x, MIN, MAX}];

Comment: Here one of the shorter example functions: https://pastebin.com/yJxyWfxy

Comment: Thanks for the example. It would be good to have in the post itself (it's not terribly large). I'll play around with it.

Comment: That's a difficult function, perhaps due to scaling of various numbers used to build it. `FindRoot` indicates there is a root around 7.43*10^(-17). On the large positive side (around 10^17) if I only take the `Re[...]` part I see a plot that indicates an interleaving of zeros and poles. With the scaling issues I'd be surprised if `CountRoots` has much of a chance even knowing the thing is (or might be) meromorphic.

Comment: Yep - What I want to do though is skip the part where CountRoots checks it is meromorphic... This is why I didn't include the function initially - my question is unrelated to any particular function really, it's about Mathematica's implementation of CountRoots. I want to know if I can skip the check before attempting to count the roots. From what I can tell, Mathematica doesn't offer this option, so I going to rewrite my own countroots function.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!